# How to select only top-level li in recursive menu?

Tags: jquery, html, css, dom

How do I select only first-level li's? If I do 'ul li', it also selects the children. Is there a way to select only the top level and not the children using CSS? If not, I am ok with using jQuery, but how would I select it in that case too?

```
<ul>
    <li class="administration first">
        <a href="/administration.aspx"><span>Administration</span></a>
        <ul>
            <li class="users first selected"><a href="/administration/users.aspx"><span>Users</span></a></li>
            <li class="forms last"><a href="/administration/forms.aspx"><span>Forms</span></a></li>
        </ul>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </li>
    <li class="analytics"><a href="/analytics.aspx"><span>Analytics</span></a></li>
    <li class="options"><a href="/options.aspx"><span>Options</span></a></li>
    <li class="system last"><a href="/system.aspx"><span>System</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `$('ul > li')` is pretty much the same as `$('ul li')` because li tags always come after ul tags. And neither answers his question.

Comment: In the list above what do you want to style?  These two li's:
<li class="administration first">
and
<li class="users first selected">
or just the first one?

Comment: @Hardware - OP wanted *first-level* `<li>` elements, which means all the immediate children of the outermost `<ul>`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You would need the element or class which is above the first ul, then specify `{parent-selector} > ul > li`.

Comment: I like this because it down not require me to change the ul menu at all such as adding a class to it. This menu is automatically generated so I do not have much control over it. So wrapping it i a div with a class works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

$("ul:first > li").

Comment: This is an excellent solution, but you must also consider other unordered-lists in the page. However, should work for the markup given, very creative.

Answer (score 5):

If your ul has a class or ID, you can do something like this:

```
$('#myList > li')
```

Comment: Down-voters should be decent, and give a reason. From the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) *"If you see misinformation, vote it down. Add comments indicating what, specifically, is wrong."*

Comment: Voted back up to zero, why was this -1?

Comment: @patrick - Agreed. If I am wrong, I would love to learn why so I can be right the next time I have to answer a question. @Deebster - Thank you for voting me back up. I appreciate it.

Comment: The vote may have come from your (brief) original answer of `$('ul li')`, but an explanation should have been given, and it should have been removed after the answer was fixed.

Answer (score 2):

A quick fix, if possible would be to add a class name on the outer ul and select with `$('ul.myClassName > li')`.

Another option: `$('ul > li:has(ul)')` it will give you all but the last nesting level.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
$('ul li:not(ul li ul li)')
```

This will select the top level only, but you'll want to use some sort of id or class selector on the first ul as well or it could interfere with page content etc

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery selector syntax for [parent/child](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) is:

```
$('ul > li')
```

> The child combinator (E > F) can be thought of as a more specific form of the descendant combinator (E F) in that it selects only first-level descendants.

With the structure you have, you may need to specify the `ul` parent element as well.

Comment: Someone is getting downvote happy (see my response, too). +1 back up for you because I don't like downvotes without a reason.

Comment: I didn't down-vote you, but this will give you the child `<li>` elements of *every* `<ul>`, including the nested one(s). You would need to add a specifier to indicate only the outer-most `<ul>`. [This example](http://jsfiddle.net/dEhC4/) will alert `6` instead of `4`, indicating that all `<li>` elements have been selected.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".analytics:parent > li")
```

Will work for this specific case, but you are better off giving the top level a class or id.

Something like:

```
$("#top-level-ul > li")
```

Seems easier to follow than having to select the parent of one of your `li`s

Answer (score 1):

How about `$('ul li').not('ul ul li')`
And you could do further nots to exclude `ul ol li` and `ol ul li` if you needed to

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to the first one if there is one with

```
  // Add a class to the first UL element      
  $(".wrapper > ul").addClass("first-level");

  // Target the first classes first li child
  $(".wrapper ul.first-level > li:first-child");
```

This has some issues with ie8 and lower.

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery traversal which generally performs better:

Given it is the first UL on the page:

```
$("ul").first().children();
```

Given that the parent element has an ID:

```
$("#TagID").find("ul").first().children();
```

Given the UL has a class:

```
$("ul.myClass").children();
```

Given the UL has an ID:

```
$("#MyID").children();
```

Given your example of the first LI having a specific class:

```
$("li.administration").parent().children();
```

Answer (score -2):

$('ul li:first')

Comment: This will select the first li tag in the list, not the top level in nested li's. Perhaps a misunderstanding of the question?

Comment: My code will return every first child li of a ul, is that not what he's asking for?

Comment: I didn't down-vote you, but the OP wanted *all* the child `<li>` elements of only the outermost `<ul>`. That's what was meant by *first-level*. :o)