# Hide first li in ul with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation menu that I'd like to hide the first item in it. e.g.

```
<ul>
   <li>Home</li>
   <li>About</li>
   <li>
      <ul>
         <li>Item 1</li>
         <li>Item 2</li>
         <li>Item 3</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

I then hide the first element like this in CSS:

```
li:first-child{
   visibility: hidden;
}
```

But then what happens is that all the first li items in the navigation disspears, like 'Item 1' in the navigation menu. How would I select **only** the 'home' li item and hide it?

Comment: add a class to your navigator ul

Comment: Related to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/977883/selecting-only-first-level-elements-in-jquery , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3892111/how-to-select-only-top-level-li-in-recursive-menu , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9084705/jquery-child-selector-only-select-top-level-child-elements

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Give your first ul a class "yourclass", then `.yourclass > li:first-child { visibility: hidden; }`

To hide the first child of the second ul use `.yourclass > li > ul > li:first-child`

Answer (score 2):

Assign a id to the first ul and then apply the css style to that id only?

```
<ul id="someid">
   <li>Home</li>
   <li>About</li>
   <li>
      <ul>
         <li>Item 1</li>
         <li>Item 2</li>
         <li>Item 3</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>

#someid > li:first-child{
   visibility: hidden;
}
```

Also see http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html

Comment: True, since the other one is also child of the first ul element!

Comment: Edit it with the ">" selector. At least this worked on my test.

Answer (score 2):

```
ul > li:first-child { (note you can do :last-child to target the last item)
display: none;
}
```

Another option, especially if you need to target other children for other reasons is to use :nth-child().  Inside the parentheses you put a number http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Using nth-child to mimick the same as the above.

```
ul > li:nth-child(1) {
display: none;
}
```

Note that nth-child is not supported by IE without a jquery library like modernizr to help it out.

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul id="abc">
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>About</li>
  <li>
  <ul>
     <li>Item 1</li>
     <li>Item 2</li>
     <li>Item 3</li>
  </ul>
</li>
</ul>
  #abc > li:first-child{
   display: none;
   }
```

Comment: This will hide both as well

Comment: The CSS rule will not work. You're still targeting all the first children that is `<li>` regardless of the level of nesting.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using:

```
body> ul>:first-child {
    display: none;
}
```

Rather than:

```
ul li:first-child{
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Any reason you'd use this rather?

Comment: Very rarely is my navigation a direct descendant of the body, why does this make more sense to you???

Answer (score 0):

You would need the element or class which is above the first ul, then specify

css soluce : {parent-selector} > ul > li.

jQuery soluce : $( "ul > li" );